# Does KVL don't hold in pn junction reverse bias?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering

Does KVL hold in pn junction reverse bias because any reference about semiconductor physics provide that figure

[image]

if we apply KVL around the loop won't be zero it will be equal to $V_{bi}$

then how KVL can't be applied?

Comment: KVL and non-linear circuit elements do not go together.

Comment: @JonCuster which mean the potential on the pn junction will be greater than the potential of the battery ?

Comment: But, more simply put, what does the circuit look like without $V_{R}$?

Comment: @JonCuster of course KVL applies to nonlinear circuits, just as it applies here as well. KVL is nothing more than the ability to *assign* a voltage drop to every element in the network. It is graph theory not physics, crudely speaking. In this question it means nothing more than that $V_R=\text{add up all the separate individual voltage drops that you wish to define along the diode}$

Comment: @hyportnex, but why in that reference kvl won't hold ?

Comment: @hyportnex, the voltage on diode is equal to $V_{bi}+V_{r}$ which means that the sum of volt on a loop won't be zero

Comment: I do not understand your question, please elaborate and also define explicitly the pieces on your diagram, for example, where $V_{bi}$ starts and where it ends, otherwise KVL cannot be applied. After you have "labeled" the diode with the various voltage drops you will be able to apply KVL.

Comment: Pick any node in the loop (e.g., the `+` terminal of the battery). Pick any instant in time. Go 'round the loop, starting from that point, adding up all of the voltage drops until you come back to the starting node. The sum _must_ be zero. Asserting that the sum is other than zero is equivalent to asserting that the voltage at the chosen node is different from the voltage at the chosen node at the chosen instant in time. That makes no sense. If you try to sum the voltage drops around a loop, and you come up with any number other than zero, you've made a mistake. Maybe you missed one.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, well that's my confusion when I apply Kvl on the figure above the result isn't zero it's $V_{bi}$ , so my question how is that possible?

Comment: I do not understand your nomenclature. $V_\text{R}$ appears to be the battery voltage. $V_\text{j}$ is what? "junction voltage?" And, what does $V_\text{bi}$? stand for? Bias voltage? I am accustomed to look at "lumped" circuit models, and to my eye, your diagram appears to show exactly two "lumps;" the battery and the diode. But your equation speaks of _three_ voltages. I don't understand where in your diagram I could measure three distinct voltages. Maybe there are more "lumps" within your mental model of the diode that are not made explicit in your diagram.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, $V_{j}$ mean the voltage on the diode and $V_{bi}$ mean the built-in voltage and the diagram shows that when we apply reverse potential $V_{R}$ to our original diode the potential on the diode will be $V_{j}=V_{bi}+V_{R}$ , so if we apply Kvl on that loop it won't hold

Comment: OK, does that mean, $V_j$ is the voltage between the diode's two terminals? If so, then $V_j=V_R$. Period. End of story. And, are you saying that $V_{bi}$ is the voltage across the junction when the diode is _not connected to anything?_ If so, then I don't believe that $V_{bi}$ is something you could measure when the diode _is_ connected to the battery as shown in your diagram. Maybe $V_{bi}$ is an important parameter in some model that predicts, for example, the current through the diode for a given $V_j$, but I am not an expert on that subject. All I know is, if you want a diagram that...

Comment: ...illustrates $V_j=V_{bi}+V_R$, then your diagram is going to need to show at least one more "lump." What that lump would represent exactly, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SolomonSlow There are *two* more lumps: the contact potentials of the metal-semiconductor junctions that connect the diode to the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The diode is connected to metal wires. Each semiconductor-metal junction has a contact potential. The sum of the contact potentials and the built-in junction potential is zero. If this were not true, a diode would act as a battery.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion because at least two models of a diode has been used simultaneously.

One (macroscopic) model has a connection between the current, $i$, passing through the diode and the voltage across it in the form of an equation of this form $i = I_0\cdot \left(e^{V_{\rm j}/V_T} - 1\right)$ where $I_0$ and $V_\rm {T}$ constants.
That being the case the application of KVL yields $V_{\rm R} -V_{\rm j} =0$.

A (microscopic) model considers the diffusion and drift of charge carriers around the junction which leads to a potential barrier being set up the height which the OP possibly has called $V_{\rm bi}$.  Although that barrier needs to be considered when discussing the operation of the diode that voltage must not be included in a KVL loop without considering other junction potentials in the loop.
As an example consider the two terminals of a diode connected together via a wire.  There will be two [metal-semiconductor junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal%E2%80%93semiconductor_junction) which need to be taken into account.

Another possibility is that $V_{\rm bi}$ is the [forward threshold voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Semiconductor_diodes), approximately $0.2\,\rm V$ for a Germanium diode and approximately $0.7\,\rm V$ for a Silicon diode.
If the applied voltage across a diode is greater than the forward threshold voltage then the diode conducts and if the applied voltage is less than the forward threshold voltage the diode will not conduct.
A diode can then be modeled as a voltage source $V_{\rm bi}$ in series with a resistor $r$.
[image]
In this case $V_{\rm j} = V_{\rm bi}+V_{\rm r}$ and again KVL can be used for the whole loop.

Comment: By $V_{bi}$ I mean the potential barrier